How to resolve uninitialized constant Nokogiri::HTML4 using Ruby in Rails
I start to learn ruby on rails
I am using ruby version 2.2.1 and rails version 4.2.7.1 to create my application , when i tried this
rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text

i get error
/home/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/loofah-2.21.1/lib/loofah/html4/document.rb:10:in `<module:HTML4>': uninitialized constant Nokogiri::HTML4 (NameError)


You should use a modern version of Ruby and Rails to start learning it. Both Ruby 2.2 and Rails 4.7 are severely outdated, won't receive any updates anymore and will show a lot of compatibility issues with current gems. Use Ruby 3.3 and Rails 8.0 instead.

Yes, I know that the versions are very old but I must use those due to the company projects created previously that continue to be supported. Is there a way to modify Nokogiri to an older compatible version?

I would really encourage you to start learning a modern version of Rails instead. It will be easier to find decent learning resources and you'll struggle a lot less with just getting it up and running. Once you understand the basic concepts it's relatively straight forward to backport the knowledge to legacy code.

That said the wisdom of your employer in bringing in someone that doesn't know Ruby or Rails to maintain legacy applications on long EOL versions of rails is somewhat questionable and you might find yourself over your head. Especially if the company doesn't have a strategy for either disbanding or upgrading the apps as keeping unsupported versions of Rails running isn't a viable option. Working on unmaintained legacy code can be one of the hardest things you can do. Not saying this to discourage you but be careful and make sure you have your bases covered if this goes tits up.

There seems to be a mismatch between gem versions. You should post your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock and try updating what you can without breakage. "Before v1.12.0, Nokogiri::HTML4 did not exist," https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/HTML4.html, so see what Nokogiri version you have and try to update it.

Any nokogiri version you can find that is compatible with ruby 2.2/rails 4 will be strewn with security vulnerabilities. Version 1.9.1 is the last version to support Ruby 2.2 and was released 6 years and 50-ish CVEs ago.¶

Probably true, @dbugger, and I don't know the reason OP is using such an old version, but that doesn't mean we can't help them fix the problem, I very much doubt it is running production workloads for any serious project.

From the post - "I start to learn ruby on rails" -- there is no reason to be using such an old version. The best way to help them fix the problem is to encourage them to use proper versions of the software, not to waste time trying to fix things that cannot be fixed.

@dbugger, we don't know the reason. I prefer to meet the questioner where they're at within the bounds of the question asked, try to answer it and identify the problem. There are plenty of other people telling them to use a newer version. Sometimes you can't upgrade the version for some reason, like incompatible other dependencies in the existing codebase. I can't think of any other reason why they would be using such an old version.

Thanks for understanding me @AndrewF
The problem is precisely that, I develop in Java but due to problems beyond my control the company requires me to support projects implemented with those versions so I have to start learning Ruby. This error occurs when I try to create a new app through the console. The project with its versions does not cause problems because they use gems from an internal repository. I will try to create my projects by downloading the old gems. Thank you
